# Java8 -> Java7 conversion File.walk

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the following snippet of Java8 to Java7:

```java
Files.walk(Paths.get(modifiedPathName))
 .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
 .forEach(path -> {
   mutatedFileStorage.add((T) application.readFromFile(path));
  });
```

I've attempted the following:

```java
Iterator<Path> it = Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(modifiedPathName)).iterator();
Path path = null;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    path = it.next();
    if(Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
            mutatedFileStorage.add((T) application.readFromFile(path));
    }
}
```

The problem is, I keep getting an error:

```java
error: no suitable method found for walkFileTree(Path)
        Iterator<Path> it = Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(modifiedPathName)).iterator();
```

I do notknow how to convert `Files.walk` to Java7, so that was my best attempt? Is there some small change I can make to my Java7 code to fix it? Or do I have to do something else entirely?

Comment: Well, is walkFileTree(Path) in the JavaDoc? By the way https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: Yes. Do I need a `FileVisitor`?

Comment: I have no idea where to start converting `Files.walk` to Java7

Comment: It returns a Stream, so you need to get an Iterator instead, which you tried, but that method isn't correct. See the JavaDoc for the correct signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going to want to use `Files.walkFileTree`:

```
final Collection<T> finalMutatedFileStorage = mutatedFileStorage;
final Application finalApplication = application; // guessing at the type here
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(modifiedPathName), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
  @Override
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
  throws IOException {
    if (attrs.isRegularFile()) {
       finalMutatedFileStorage.add((T) finalApplication.readFromFile(file));
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }
});
```

Comment: `error: no suitable method found for walkFileTree(String,<anonymous SimpleFileVisitor<Path>>)`

Comment: You need to pass a Path as the first argument. `Files.walkFileTree(Path.get(modifiedPathName), ...`

Comment: Also, `path` isn't defined! In addition, I keep getting a host of inner class errors.

Comment: The errors I get after modifying your solution are both: `local variable mutatedFileStorage/application is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`. (And I think it's `Paths.get`)

Comment: Sorry, made a few copy/paste errors, I wasn't writing this in an IDE. Anything that's used within the anonymous `SimpleFileVisitor` is going to need to be declared as a final variable. (`mutatedFileStorage`, `application`). If you can't do that, you can declare a final "copy" of them outside of the walkFileTree call. (Updated with example)